Не запускается PyCharm на MacOS
Дело заключается вот в чем. Я установил PyCharm Community Edition через jetbrain.com, в окне, где меня просят перенести PyCharm в папку Applications. Приложение успешно переносится, но у него зачеркнутый логотип, и при попытке открыть его через файндер, высвечивается уведомление: "Нельзя открыть программу PyCharm, т.к. она не поддерживается этим компьютером Мас". Много раз переустанавливал с сайта версию именно для Мас ОС. Что делать?

устнаовить версию, которая поддерживается?

Вы получили очень информативный ответ - установлена версия, которая не соответствует вашей операционной системе. Для более содержательного ответа укажите, какая у вас версия операционной системы и какая конкретно сборка PyCharm использована при установке.

Версия, которую вы пытаетесь установить не подходит для вашей версии MacOS попробуйте выбрать версию постарше или помладше
